# Как получить данные из POST запроса в JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, post

можно ли как-то получить данные из пост запроса в JS, как, например, в php - $_POST?

Comment: Можно. Используйте ajax, fetch или аналоги.

Answer (score 2):

Я предпочитаю использовать axios.

```
const axios = require('axios');
const apiResponse = (await axios.post(`/api/path`, requestBody)).data;
console.log(apiResponse);
```

Answer (score 1):

Для Node.js

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
app.use(express.urlencoded())
app.use(express.json());
 
app.post('/api/test', function(req, res){
    console.log('req.body', req.body)
    res.send(JSON.stringify(req.body));
});
 
app.listen(3000);
```